# Migrating from SQL Server to AWS Aurora

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-web-services

My organization is considering moving our current SQL Server RDS instance to an AWS Aurora instance. Our motivation is solely to cut down on costs. I have run some successful tests using the MySQL Workbench Database Migration tool to move the SQL Server db to an Aurora instance. The database is about 4GB, has about 100 tables, about a dozen views and stored procedures. I am already using a MySQL copy of the database for development on a local machine, so all SQL syntax differences are already handled.

Are there any serious downsides to this migration project? Anything we should consider before making the switch?

Comment: Good question, but did not get the reasoning. What makes you think that SQL Server Express won't accommodate your needs?

Comment: You have to test out the store procedures top priority with Aurora RDS.

Comment: Thanks, Slava. I'm trying Express in a test environment. It seems to read fast, but the writes (saving data from a web form) are very slow compared to our current db.m3.xlarge instance. db.t2.medium is the largest type for Express. The CPU seems fine. Maybe it's the lack of PIOPS-optimized that is making the difference?

Comment: Aurora will be supporting Postgres in the near future as well (in preview now). https://pages.awscloud.com/amazon-aurora-with-postgresql-compatibility-preview-form.html

Answer (score 8):

This is a really series step. You should consider a few key things while migrating:

1. **Performance**: for simple request Aurora (improved MySQL) can be faster than MS SQL, but:
   a) MS SQL has smarter query analyzer and in order to take good Aurora (MySQL) performance you need to understand how it works very well. SQL Server can “excuse” a lot of developer things.
   b) For such big databases SQL Server in Enterprise edition has a few great features: **partitioning**, **data compressions**, **online rebuild indexes**, always on. But Enterprise edition can be expensive enough. That’s true.
2. **Development**: MySQL (Aurora) syntax is really poor comparing to SQL Server. MySQL doesn’t support many many things like HierarchyID, recurrent CTE, included column in indexes, index filtering, change tracking, XML, JSON and so on. It even limites systax for nested queries a lot. Many thing you need to implement yourself. Also, SQL Server has more professional development tools like SQL Server Management Tool, SQL Profiler, and Tuning Adviser and so on.
3. **Different implementations**: Some things in Aurora work differently. For instance, unique index in Aurora allows having many null values but SQL Server doesn't allow this. And so on.
4. **Priсe**: For good performance for now you need to rent at least large Aurora instance which costs about $210 p/m + replica = about $420 - not so cheap. [Amazon Aurora Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/pricing/?nc1=h_ls)

So, I’d recommend calculating all pros and cons while migrating because you can reduce resource cost but spend additional time and affords (so money) on development and maintenance.

Comment: Thanks, Vasyl. 1-3 are great points, but it was ultimately 4 that turned us away from Aurora. To get comparable instance we would be saving almost nothing.

Comment: Right, you can save not a lot money, a little bit in case for high-loaded huge databases.